# Adding constraints behave differently, adjusts to prior values instead of new

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

In previous versions of Xcode, when adding constraints to views the view would change according to the constraints that were added. If the orange view below had an already defined constraint to the bottom and to the right and I would proceed to add equal width and height as the green view the views would result in overlapping each other. Now the orange width and height constraint would update their multiplier to be around 0.5

Anyone know how to turn off this change of behaviour? Really frustrating having to going into each constraint and changing them to 1.0 when that's what they should have already been.

[image: Green and orange views]

Answer (score 0):

Do it in code instead of the storyboard.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    orangeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerXAnchor),
    orangeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.centerYAnchor),
    orangeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.trailingAnchor),
    orangeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.bottomAnchor)
      ])
```